# Remix server side image is not loading and fetch is returning null inside child component

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, server-side-rendering, remix.run

[image]I was following the tutorial [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-basics-of-remix/#:%7E:text=Remix%20does%20this%20in%20a,render%20a%20random%20cat%20image.)
to render an image from server side my code looks something like this

```
import { Outlet, useLoaderData } from '@remix-run/react';

export async function loader() {
  const response = await fetch('https://picsum.photos/500/300');
  return {
    imageUrl: response.url,
  };
}

export default function RandomImageLayout() {
  const imageData = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

  return (
    <>
      <img
        src={imageData.imageUrl}
        alt="Random Image"
        style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }}
      />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
}
```

The code works when i am using it in the _index.tsx because i am accessing the route data using useLoaderData.

But the same code when used inside a component say a contact-us component inside the _index.tsx it won't work and returns null

since i want to load a different image for my contact-us component i wanted to use useloaderData() inside it and it returns null

How can i use differnt useLoaderData() for multiple componets under the same route?

Or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a Response from your loader and action.

```
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";

export async function loader() {
  const response = await fetch('https://picsum.photos/500/300');
  const data = { imageUrl: response.url }

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  // OR SIMPLY

  return json(data);
}
```

Learn More: https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/loader